# What causes "Method 'foo' is defined in class 'Bar' and is not visible" in AppCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, appcode

Given the following method:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    if ([allTouches count] > 0)
    {
        _lastUserTouchTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    }

    [super sendEvent:event];
}
```

The [event allTouches] generates the following inspection warning in AppCode 2016.3.

> "Method 'allTouches' is defined in class 'UIEvent' and is not visible"

allTouches is defined in **<UIKit/UIEvent.h>** which I've tried including to no effect. Xcode doesn't seem to have any issue with this bit of code. Anyone have insight on this?

Comment: It looks correct. Have you tried it in an event delegate?  Like; -(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `allTouches` is defined as property

Look at this code:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UIEvent : NSObject
...
#if UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nullable) NSSet <UITouch *> *allTouches;
#else
- (nullable NSSet <UITouch *> *)allTouches;
#endif
...
@end
```

Later versions of iOS SDK uses properties rather than methods. And, AppCode has more strict type-checks than Xcode. That's why Xcode silently compiles and AppCode gives warnings